# Will a Django Webapplication work on a Hostpoint standard Webserver?

Tags: django, web-hosting, wsgi

I can't seem to find any confirmation anywhere that the [standard webhosting service for HostPoint](https://www.hostpoint.ch/en/webhosting/webhosting.html) will be able to host my Django project. They seem to suggest I need a Managed Server to run my project, is that the case? I'm kind of new to all of this so I'm sorry if this is a stupid question.

I've rummaged through Hostpoint's site and can't find anything that helps me further, I've even written an email to host point themselves to but still haven't gotten an answer any lead will be helpful.